# Java generics type erasure of method parameters

Tags: java, generics, types

I got this one from a google I/O puzzler talk given by Joshua Bloch. Here's the code

```
 public class Glommer<T> {
      String glom(Collection<?> obj){
         String result = "";
         for(Object o : obj){
              result += o;
         }
         return result;
      }

      int glom(List<Integer> ints){
           int result = 0;
           for(int i : ints){
                result += i;
           }
           return result;
       }

      public static void main(String args[]){
           List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
           System.out.println(new Glommer().glom(strings));
      }
```

this main method throws an exception because `new Glommer` is a raw type and hence all the generics in `Glommer` is erased, so it ends up calling `int glom(List<Integer> ints)` rather than `String glom(Collection<?> obj)`.

My question is, even if I called `glom()` as `new Glommer<Integer>().glom(strings)` shouldn't it call the `int glom(List<Integer> ints)` method since due to type erasure, this method is effectively `int glom(List ints)` and `strings` is of type `List` not `Collection`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The called method is defined at compilation time, not at runtime.

If you add a parameter to your constructor call, the compiler will have enough information to know that it has to call the first method. Otherwise, it's just as if generics didn't exist. In both case, the called method will always stay the same at runtime.

EDIT Some people seem to doubt, so here's another example:

```
public class Test {

    private static void test(Object object) {
        System.out.println("Object method");
    }

    private static void test(Integer integer) {
        System.out.println("Integer method");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object object = Integer.valueOf(0);
        test(object);
    }

}
```

The result is:

```
Object method
```

You pass an Integer to your method, but all that the compiler knows at compile time is that it's an object. The jvm doesn't automagically change the method call even though the Object is actually an Integer.

Comment: I'd say that compiler determines the signature of the method to execute, but a method to execute is chosen at runtime using actual object type.

Comment: @tcb I added an example, try it.

Comment: I understand what you want to say and in this example you're correct, but my words were about a general case where you can have a derived class with overridden methods.

Comment: @tcb In the case where a method is chosen by dynamic dispatch (override), that's still the same method signature. The method signature to call (overload) is chosen at compile time. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about [Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) to understand it fully

Basically, raw types are for using legacy code, almost anything in a raw class will become raw itself, in this case those 2 methods.

So when it is raw there is a method that gets a `List` and one for `Collection` so its called the `List` one, if its not raw, the methods are not raw also and it will call the `Collection` one because it has the extra information

Answer (score 0):

This is because when `new Glommer()` is called without generics the `Generic<Type>()`, all of type matches are removed from the class.

As strings variable is a `List`, if it does not have any generic `<Type>` then it will match the `glom(List ints)`. The type checking doesn't get done till later.

When we create `new Glommer<AnyType>` the types are all left in place, so when we pass our `strings` variable it does type checking. The compiler can now check if it is a `List<Integer>`, which is not so it gets passed to the `glom(Collection<?> obj)` method.

Hope this helps, please ask for any clarification if you need!